# How to handle short and long button clicks

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

How i can handle short and long button clicks? I need some specific action on short button click and specific action on long button click.
I read about Gesture Listener and try to implement it into Android MainActivity.cs file(MainActivity class). But i have exception when application runs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.Page">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="MyButton" Grid.Row="0" />
    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
      <Label x:Name="MyLabel" HorizontalOptions="Center">...</Label>
    </ScrollView>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You may want to add the Xamarin.Forms tag to this post as well. Please also post any exceptions you run into within your question. There's also a straight forward tutorial here: http://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you could use a custom renderer for the button. Each platform would have its own way of handling a long gesture which is not currently exposed through the forms button.

On Android:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer (typeof (MyButton), typeof (MyButtonRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Android
{   
    public class MyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<global::Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
                {
                    base.OnElementChanged (e);
                    if (e.OldElement == null) {
                        var nativeButton = Control;
                        nativeButton.LongClick += delegate {
                            //Do something
                        };
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

On iOS:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(ButtonWithLongPressGesture), typeof(LongPressGestureRecognizerButtonRenderer))]
namespace SampleApp.iOS
{
    public class LongPressGestureRecognizerButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        ButtonWithLongPressGesture view;

        public ButtonPressGestureRecognizerImageRenderer ()
        {
            this.AddGestureRecognizer (new UILongPressGestureRecognizer ((longPress) => {
                if (longPress.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
                    view.HandleLongPress(view, new EventArgs());
                }
            }));
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
                view = e.NewElement as ButtonWithLongPressGesture;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But how it works with button that placed into XAML(i need to write somewhere references to this or not)? When this code called? Thanks again!

Comment: You would use it like any custom control. See this guide on how to create and use a custom renderer https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/entry/

Comment: FYI - I believe you have a typo. Your constructor and class name do not match.